# awk to print html text on line, syntax error

Tags: awk, syntax, quotes

Trying to use `awk` to parse the contents of `file` and print the html line, but getting a syntax error on the last`"`` Thank you :).

**file**

```
1 2 3 4
```

**awk**

```
awk '{print $2,<html><head></head><body><hr><a href="https://website.com/bbp/view/id/p/start.php" target="_blank">'
```

also tried to escape some of the special characters:

```
awk '{print $2,"<html><head></head><body><hr>""<a href=""https://website.com/bbp/view/id/p/start.php" target="_blank"">"'
```

**desired**

```
2 <html><head></head><body><hr><a href="https://website.com/bbp/view/id/p/start.php" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape double quotes within quotes and add final `}`:

```
awk '{print $2, "<html><head></head><body><hr><a href=\"https://website.com/bbp/view/id/p/start.php\" target=\"_blank\">"}' /tmp/FILE
```